# Sybase db connection using jtds driver getting failed with no response

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase, jtds, sap-cloud-platform

I have a Sybase db in SAP cloud and successfully opened a tunnel to it through command prompt and then connected thorough eclipse data source explorer.Now i am trying to write a simple java programme which will connect to this DB and read/update data in to it.I have tried both jdbc4 driver(jconn4.jar) and jtds driver(jtds-1.3.1.jar) to make this connection and in both cases programme execution is getting stopped after calling getConnection() method. Below is the sample code.

```
try {
    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
    System.out.println("Connecting to database ...");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(
         "jdbc:jtds:sybase://localhost:30015/dbname?ssl=require","id","pwd");
    System.out.println("Database connected");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

No error in the console but programme execution is getting stopped after printing `"Connecting to database ..."`.

I am using java 8 with eclipse Neon.3.

Anybody can please suggest me what might be the problem with the above code? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the connection actually works? Have you been able to connect using another tools? Have you tried a JDBC connection using for example SquirrelSQL?

Comment: I haven't used any other tools, as it is a Sybase db i tried with the above two mentioned jars but nothing is working.As i said earlier i have opened a tunnel in my local machine to the remote db and trying to connect using the tunnel.When the tunnel is closed i got an error like connection refused ,but when the tunnel is opened it simply returns nothing.

Comment: I can view and edit the data of this remote DB using eclipse data explorer, but couldn't find a way to do the same using a java programme as i am getting failed to create a connection.

Comment: Have you tried disabling SSL on the server and trying to connect without the SSL parameters from the client side?

Comment: No,i dont have that privileges,the remote DB is in client premises.

Comment: As I have understood the query works fine with Eclipse but does not work with custom code. Is the connection string exactly the same in both approaches? Is the database driver the same? Is the java class and jars the same?

Comment: Yes i have used jConnect for JDBC (jconn4.jar) for connecting through eclipse data explorer.I am using the same to connect through java program.If i pass the property value to accept all the certificates and form the connection then jvm execution is suspending after calling getCoonection method.If i remove that property and try then i am getting an exception "sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target ".

Comment: This issue is probably related to some security (SSL) Java parameters / classes. I would recommend to install a ASE database server instance on the host you are working and try experiment with the connection to this server first. You would have the full abilities to test all possible network issues. And when all works fine - just change the IP/port to your production server.